# What is expectation of $X$?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

Let $A[1:n]$ be an array such that $A[i]=i$ for $i=1,\dots,n$.

An algorithm randomly permutes the elements of $A$, and call the resulting array $A'$.

Let $X$ denote the number of locations such that $A'[i]=i$.

> What is expectation of $X$?

Comment: What have you tried? Where do you get stuck? Hint: the expectation is linear, so $E[X + Y] = E[X] + E[Y]$, even when $X, Y$ are not independent.

Comment: like E[X] = 1* (1/n) + 2 *(1/n)......... (since E[X]= summation (x)*P(x))..

Answer (score 1):

Let $X_i$ take value $1$ if $A'[i]=i$ and let it take value $0$ otherwise.

Then: $$X=\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$$

Apply linearity of expectation as suggested in comment of **Mees**.

Comment: Can you please give complete solution,.. i am not completely clear

Comment: Can you find $\mathbb EX_1$? That is the expectation of a random variable that only takes values in $\{0,1\}$, so that $\mathbb EX_1=0\times P(X_1=0)+1\times P(X_1=1)=P(X_1=1)$.

Comment: E[X1] = 0* ((n-1)/n) + 1 *(1/n) ?

Comment: Yes, and of course $\mathbb EX_i=\mathbb EX_1=\frac1{n}$ for every $i$. Now apply that $\mathbb EX=\sum_{i=1}^n\mathbb EX_i$ (linearity of expectation).

Comment: 1/n + 1/n +...... n times =1 ?

Comment: Indeed. That's all.